# Observer pattern in swift with default implementations

Tags: swift, protocols

This is my code:

```
public protocol Subjectable: class {
    associatedtype T

    var observers: [T] { get set }

    func addObserver(_ observer: T)
    func removeObserver(_ observer: T)
    func removeAllObservers()
}

public extension Subjectable {
    func removeAllObservers() {
        observers.removeAll()
    }

    func removeObserver(_ observer: T) {
        observers = observers.filter { $0 !== observer.self } // error
    }

    func addObserver(_ observer: T) {
        observers.append(observer.self)
    }
}
```

I got an error saying

> Binary operator '!==' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and
>   'Self.T'

I am not sure what it wants to tell me. I can add observers without problems with the `.self` suffix. I can however get rid of the compile error by adding `: AnyObject` behind `associatedtype T`, but than I can not create a protocol and a class which compiles ( I got errors saying the protocol does not conform to `AnyObject`, regardless if I add `: AnyObject` behind the protocol)

Is there any way I can create an observer pattern with protocols and default implementations which compiles and which I can use (create protocol and classes :) ).

Edit: the observer is a protocol as well, not a class.

edit 2: this works (but I have to re-implement the addObserver method all the time)

```
public protocol MyProtocol: AnyObject {}

public class MyClass: Subjectable {
    public var observers = [MyProtocol]()

    public func removeObserver(_ observer: MyProtocol) {
        observers = observers.filter { $0 === observer }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `observers = observers.filter { $0 !== observer }`?

Comment: @Sweeper I want to use the associatedtype as a protocol, not as a class. Do you know how that will work out?

Answer (score 1):

Your belief that `T` must be a class (`AnyObject`) is correct. You don't need to use `.self` anywhere here.

```
public protocol Subjectable: class {
    associatedtype T: AnyObject // Require T to be a class type for !==
    // ...
}

public extension Subjectable {
    // ...
    func removeObserver(_ observer: T) {
        observers = observers.filter { $0 !== observer }  // Remove .self
    }

    func addObserver(_ observer: T) {
        observers.append(observer) // Remove .self
    }
}
```

Then you can implement it thus, with default implementations:

```
class O {}

class X: Subjectable {
    var observers: [O] = []
}
```

Comment: Hey Rob, maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question to state that I am using the associatedtype T as a protocol (So not a class like O). T will always be a protocol. Indeed, this will compile, but I can not use T as a protocol because I get errors when I try to do so (details are in the question)

Comment: The observer cannot be a protocol. A protocol is not a class, and you require a class for `!==`. A protocol that requires a type to be a class is still not a class. It's still a protocol. In Swift, protocols do not conform to themselves. You will need to redesign this to not require `T` to be a protocol or to not use `!==` (for instance by using `Equatable` instead of `AnyObject`).

Comment: Note that using `Equatable` here will almost certainly explode because of `Self` requirements. You need to carefully consider why you're using a protocol here, and see how you can remove it. Protocols dramatically complicate Swift. Do not inject them unless they are serving a very powerful purpose.

Comment: Yes, but it can't be a protocol and do what you're trying to do with it. You can't access `===` inside a protocol relying on another protocol that you claim is a class. Yes, Swift has a few special cases that can work (like arrays of protocol objects inside of concrete types), but they're not generalized (i.e. this doesn't mean you can use an array of protocol objects inside of a protocol reliably). You're pushing protocols past where they work in Swift. Building complex systems on top of protocols is very fragile in Swift today, and filled with weird corner cases.